# Can only type numbers 9 < 37 only

Tags: javascript

How can I make an input type only numbers, and only numbers less than 36 and greater than 9 available? Can you do this in JavaScript?

I have this to only let numbers allowed in an input:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You want to prevent users to "type" numbers greater than 36 and less than 9?

Comment: So you press `3` and then `1` and for none of them a digit will appear on the screen? No, please validate your input *on submission*, not while typing.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this can be done. Just use `isNaN()` (is not a number). So what you want is basically

```
if(!isNaN(number) && (number > 9 && number < 36)){
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do something else like alert user that they need to enter a number between 10 and 35
}
```

Just to be clear, you'd be using `!` so that `!isNaN(10)` will return true since `isNaN(10)` would come back as false, so we need to make it a truthy value.

Edit: I'm guessing you're new to this, so I'm going to adhere to your request and help you out a bit:

```
if (!isNaN(number) && (number > 9 && number < 36)) {
    //do stuff
} else if (isNaN(number)) {
    alert('Please enter a number');
} else if (number <= 9 || number >= 36) {
    alert('Please enter a number between 10 and 35');
}
```

Take this as a learning experience. Follow the logic. Break your problem into smaller problems.

Comment: Could you add text that says the number is too big? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to help you out a bit. I hope you've been able to learn something :)

Comment: Yeah. I'm missing something. Not working. Let me check.

Comment: Yeah. does it fit the code above to It will work side by side with it?